# How to delete several adjacent virtual memory allocations with one VirtualFree call?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, virtual-memory

Below is just a short test code sample to illustrate my question:

```
SYSTEM_INFO si;
GetSystemInfo(&si);

//Go by allocation granularity to have a chance to reserve adjacent memory chunks
size_t szAlloc = si.dwAllocationGranularity;

//Try to alloc two adjacent memory chunks
BYTE* pp1 = (BYTE *)::VirtualAlloc(NULL, szAlloc, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
ASSERT(pp1);
BYTE* pp2 = (BYTE *)::VirtualAlloc(pp1 + szAlloc, szAlloc, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
ASSERT(pp2);

//We should be able to write between them
WORD ui = 0xAB;
BYTE* p = pp1 + szAlloc - sizeof(ui) / 2;
*(WORD*)p = ui;

//Release both at once
BOOL bb = ::VirtualFree(pp1, szAlloc + szAlloc, MEM_RELEASE);
int err = ::GetLastError();
```

How can I free both memory chunks with one call? Or consolidate them into one chunk, if freeing at once is not allowed? (The reason I'm asking is because in my actual code there can be more than just 2 adjacent chunks.)

PS. In the test code above `VirtualFree` fails with error code `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`.

Comment: The other problem with your code is that there's no guarantee that the second chunk of address space will actually be available.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, that is true. Like I said it's a test code to illustrate the concept. In a real scenario if the second chunk is not available, I'll have to `VirtualAlloc` the whole thing and `memcpy` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you want. Although i'm not sure exactly why you would want to - if you need to free multiple allocations then free them all seperately.

However, I think you can partially achieve what you want by reserving a single, large piece of memory (via `auto ptr = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, ..., MEM_RESERVE, ...);` and then piece-wise commitng the bits of that larger allocation when you want to via `VirtualAlloc((uint_t*)ptr+offset, ..., MEM_COMMIT, ...);`.

If you do this then you can free the whole large reservation (including all pieces you've individually committed in it) with a single call vid `VirtualFree(ptr, 0, MEM_RELEASE)`

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. But I can call `VirtualLock(pp1, szAlloc * 2);` across them just fine. The reason I can't do `reserve` first is that I don't know the initial size. The memory requirement can grow over time.

Comment: If you're using a 64bit app then just reserve a large enough block for whatever you max size will be (reserving doesn't use memory, it just takes up address space). 32bit apps may be more of an issue if you think you'll run low on address space. I'm not an expert with VirtualLock but looking at its docs it seems like it would work in this scenario.

Comment: for *VirtualLock* important only that whole memory range will be valid. even if it form different allocations. but *VirtualFree* can free only all or part of allocated(reserved) memory range. not another range. and for what you need *VirtualLock* ?